Error when setting an S3 Policy & CloudFront : Policy has invalid action (only action being "S3.GetObject")
I'm trying to set up an S3 Express Zone storage class, which only works with directory buckets.
To allow public access to the file (unauthenticated, with a URL), I understand I need to create a CloudFront distribution, which I did.
When creating the following bucket policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipalReadOnly",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3express:eu-north-1:851725228246:bucket/gscript--eun1-az1--x-s3/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::851725228246:distribution/ED3ORK2PVOR4C"
            }
        }
    }
}

I get the following error : Policy has invalid action
Error screenshot
I tried several syntax, but I can't create that policy. I'm also exploring other option to make that directory bucket available online, any idea welcome.

What is your goal here? Is it to allow unauthenticated users to get objects from your bucket, is it to do the same but only via CloudFront, or is it to allow an IAM user to get the objects?

Allow unauthenticated users to get objects, and from what I understand CloudFront is the best option for directory buckets (can't disable public blocks).
I'll remove the IAM part from the original post, as it's just confusing.
